# When you give it out in the wrong way

Tags: word, steganography, password

To know the secrets of the universe and hence attain ultimate power, you just need to enter a four-letter password. All you have is a sheet of paper
with the following written on it, which is supposed to be a clue. Can you read between the lines and make out the password?

> To You, Dear!
>
> Try it just deviously; this is easy, Mr. Puzzler Omniscient. Knowledge about all languages aids. Don't enter nonsense, BS or rubbish answers. Zero experience in this? Hang on, read again this epistle, minding peculiar unusual specialities. Simple afterthoughts may assist you.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The password is

> TIME

Because

> The first letters of each sentence/clause spell a word that translates to time in another language
>  
> To You, Dear! -> **Tyd** (Afrikaans) 
>  Try it just deviously -> **Tijd** (Dutch) 
>  this is easy, Mr. Puzzler Omniscient -> **tiempo** (Spanish)
>  Knowledge about all languages aids -> **kaala** (Sanskrit)
>  Don't enter nonsense, BS or rubbish answers -> **denbora** (Basque) 
>  Zero experience in this? -> **zeit** (German)
>  Hang on, read again -> **hora** (Galician) 
>  this epistle, minding peculiar unusual specialities -> **tempus** (Latin)
>  Simple afterthoughts may assist you -> **samay** (Hindi)

And the title...

> **When you give it out** *the wrong way* = **EMIT** *backwards* = **TIME**

Comment: Nice! So do you now "know the secrets of the universe and hence attain ultimate power"? If so, just know that I upvoted, Benevolent Overlord.

Comment: @Dan Mr. Puzzler Omniscient totally knew that.

Comment: Wonderful answer, quick too. (Urdu)

Answer (score 0):

The password is

> DEAR

Because

> It's written explicitly as a clue: "To You, Dear!"

Comment: i thought of that but couldt be that simple