# The Beginning Stops at the End

Tags: password

After a few minutes of thought, [the password finally becomes obvious](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38377/when-you-give-it-out-in-the-wrong-way/). You can sense your body shivering as you slide the letters into correct position with quivering fingers. The 'D' at the last slot slides into an 'E', and a creaking of intricate mechanisms welcomes you in. To your dismay, you find another door, waiting for **two** four-letter passwords to be entered.

$\qquad \;\;$ [image]

"Ugh, I should've known. It couldn't be that easy.", you groan.
Looking around in utter despair, you spy a note lurking from one of the cracks. You pick it up; it reads:

> Store cut into pieces confine chef rooster. Jump schusses heavens speaks pouches bag foot covering. Slide cut break cleaner immerse hose.

Can you crack the code once again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was almost there and had the same sequence as hexomino, but I have found the passwords. They are:

> SHIP and DOCK

First part of the note:

> Store: SHOP
>  cut into pieces: CHOP
>  confine: COOP (verb, as in "coop up")
>  chef: COOK
>  rooster: COCK

Second part:

> Jump: SKIP
>  schusses: SKIS
>  heavens: SKYS ("skies")
>  speaks: SAYS
>  pouches: SACS
>  bag: SACK
>  foot covering: SOCK

Third part:

> Slide: SLIP
>  cut: SNIP
>  break: SNAP
>  cleaner: SOAP
>  immerse: SOAK
>  hose: SOCK

Note that

> each word in the three sequences is formed by changing one letter in the previous word.

Then note that

> the first and last word are similar in each sequence, and changing one letter in each gives us a word that comes at the beginning of all three sequences. The only word that fits is SHIP, so SHIP is the first password.

The last word

> could be various words: LOCK, ROCK, etc, but the title says "The Beginning stops at the End". If the beginning is SHIP, then the end must be DOCK (a ship stops at a dock).

EDIT: cleaned up

Comment: This is the correct answer! Would you mind cleaning it up for future readers?

Comment: @Ankoganit: Done.

Comment: @M Oehm: Also done.

Answer (score 8):

I think the answers are

> **Start here:** SHOP 
>  **Finish here:** SOCK

Reasoning

> Each word or phrase corresponds to a four letter word and we connect one to the next by changing one letter. The second sentence needs to be read backwards to make the links work.

**First sentence**
Store

> SHOP

cut into pieces

> CHOP

confine

> COOP

chef

> COOK

rooster.

> COCK

**Second sentence backwards**
foot covering.

> SOCK

bag

> SACK

pouches

> SACS

speaks

> SAYS

heavens

> SKYS (SKIES)

schusses

> SKIS

Jump

> SKIP

**Third sentence**
Slide

> SLIP

cut

> SNIP

break

> SNAP

cleaner

> SOAP

immerse

> SOAK

hose.

> SOCK

Comment: You were sooo close....